# Chrome Extension API: capturing specific tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Right now I developing a product based on Chromium extension which monitors user actions by taking screenshots on several DOM events, such as mouse "click". I using `chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab` API for doing that.

The problem: if user makes a click on tab "A" content and then very fast choosing another tab "B" - captureVisibleTab takes screenshot of currently visible tab "B" (instead of tab "A", where action happened).

This is because it take some time while "click" message passing from content script to background (asynchronously) and screenshot taken (also asynchronously) and during that time another tab already activated.

One possible solution I had been thinking is instead of using "captureVisibleTab" - use some another capture API which takes tab id as an argument - but I cannot find such API.

Any ideas?

Comment: What you can do is, freeze the tab when a user clicks to capture until the capture is done.